# Generate a list of fixed value for sum of entries

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension

I want to generate a list of `n` probabilities with the sum of probabilities amounting to 1. The list is of fixed size, but could be arbitrarily large. So `n` could be `111`, `2`, `10`, `14`, `100`, etc. I realize that this might be a computational challenge of sorts and there might not be one best way of doing this but I would  still gladly appreciate suggestions for a reasonable approach.

Comment: What sort of a distribution are you looking for? Obviously a naive way is simply a uniform distribution where each value is `1/n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this I think is generate a list of random numbers of the desired size, add all numbers and divide every number by the total:

```
randlist = [randon.random() for i in range(n)]
total = sum(randlist)
randlist = [i/total for i in randlist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Smetterleen but perhaps slightly more efficient:

```
import random
def generate(n):
    unnormalised = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
    s = sum(unnormalised)
    normalised = map(lambda x: x/s, unnormalised)
    return normalised
```

*Worth noting that neither of these will necessarily sum to **precisely** to 1*:

```
>>> sum(generate(4))
1.0
>>> sum(generate(4))
1.0
>>> sum(generate(4))
1.0000000000000002
>>> sum(generate(4))
0.9999999999999999
>>> sum(generate(4))
1.0
```

Comment: more efficient - [random.random() for _ in itertools.repeat(None, n)]